# How do I find out if my string has overflowed to the next line

Tags: .net, vb.net, pdf-generation, dynamic-data

I'm adding some content within a long concatenated string (it's horrible, I know).

I have to display 3 columns of data from a datatable and my code looks like this.

```
        If Not IsNothing(MyBase.EligibilityQuestions) Then
            Dim sw As System.IO.StringWriter
            For Each row As DataRow In MyBase.EligibilityQuestions.Rows
                sw = New System.IO.StringWriter

                For Each col As DataColumn In MyBase.EligibilityQuestions.Columns
                    sw.Write(row(col).ToString() & ", ")
                Next
                OverFlowEndorsments &= sw.ToString()
                OverFlowEndorsments &= nl
            Next
        End If
```

My problem is I end up with text that overflows to a new line and doesn't line up with the text from the column it belongs, I'm writing this for a DynamicPDF so I can't insert HTML, and I'm trying to get this to look like a table (all the columns lined up).

Short of Counting characters in each line, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: can you paste in here what you are ending up with exactly..? also within the for each loop why are you creating a new StringWriter can you move the sw = New System.IO.StringWriter outside the first for each loop, does VB.NET use a StringBuilder like we use in C# .NET if so create an Instance of that object and use the append method and when done write the stringbuilder.ToString() contents to the StringWriter

Answer (score 0):

I think that you've got two possible problems:

Firstly, you're writing out the equivalent of a CSV rather than a fixed width. So the output will be different for each line depending on the data used. Try switching to outputting fixed width strings using 'PadLeft' or 'PadRight' to insert spaces as required.

Secondly, your data may just be too big for the space it's going into, in which case you'll maybe need to reformat your PDF target or somehow truncate the data going in.